# Scroll through all fancyBox galleries

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I'm using [fancyBox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) which works like a charm.

I have several different galleries on one page.

Is it somehow possible to scroll through all the galleries instead of just the images in one gallery?

The reason for not collecting all images in ONE gallery, is due to the fact that I need to have thumbnails separated from gallery to gallery.

Comment: I guess the answer to "_Is it somehow possible to scroll through all the galleries instead of just the images in one gallery?_" is, it's not possible the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

As fancybox support multiple type of content you could technically have div containers for all galleries and then try to apply fancy box to the gallery elements. Maybe something like this

```
<div id="galleries">
  <div class="gallery"><!-- content here --></div>
  <div class="gallery"><!-- content here --></div>
  <div class="gallery"><!-- content here --></div>
</div>

$(function() {
  $(".gallery").fancybox();
  $("#galleries").fancybox();
});
```

Not sure how fancybox will handle having 2 instances of it running at the same time tho, it would work for sure if you use iframes to have gallery in them, but controlling that for it too look good might take some fiddling and well it's not a pretty solution.